How to migrate a simple WebObjects 5 application to a Java-based Spring Boot/MVC web application?
I am working on migrating a legacy WebObjects 5 web application (documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_5/WebObjectsOverview/WebObjectsOverview.pdf) to a modern Java-based Spring Boot/MVC web application. The current WebObjects app is a simple web application that uses MySQL for database storage.
Can anyone provide guidance or steps on how to achieve the following?
Data Layer Migration:
WebObjects uses Enterprise Objects (EOs) for ORM. How can I migrate WebObjects EO models to Spring Boot's JPA/Hibernate with MySQL?
UI Migration:
WebObjects uses WOComponents for UI rendering. What is the best way to migrate these to Spring Boot MVC controllers and views (JSP or Thymeleaf)?
Business Logic Migration:
The WebObjects app has business logic in its WOActions. What’s the best way to migrate this to Spring Boot's Service layer?
Session Management:
How can I handle session management in Spring Boot similar to WebObjects' session handling?
URL Routing:
How can I map the WebObjects URL routing to Spring Boot controllers?
Is there any specific tooling or libraries that can help with this migration?
Thank you for your help!
So far I was not able to find any open source/3rd party tool/library that can help with this.

I think you'll have a very hard time with this. Depending on how EOF is used, it will be very hard to replicate its functionality in other frameworks.
WO "routing" works pretty different to regular URL routing you'll find today.
There are FOSS implementations of WO, including https://github.com/GETobjects
Probably best to reimplement from scratch in a modern environment.

Thanks. Reimplement from scratch is what we have as our first strategy for now.
